# How do you grab the first letter in a string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working with an entity (Employee) that has 3 fields: FirstName, LastName, & Login

I want to grab the lastname and the first letter of the firstname field and write this to the login field. How do I grab the first letter of the firstname?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the first *character* (not necessarily a letter) use an index into the string:

```
char c = employee.FirstName[0];
```

You may also want to first check that the string is non-null and non-empty and strip leading whitespace, and that the first character is actually a letter:

```
if (employee != null && employee.FirstName != null) {
    string name = employee.FirstName.TrimStart();
    if (name.Length > 0) {
        char firstChar = name[0];
        if (char.IsLetter(firstChar)) {
            employee.Login = firstChar.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `name` should better not be empty.

Comment: Yes, looks better. But the -1 isn't mine.

Answer (score 4):

Just as simple as:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Employee.FirstName))
{
    string firstLetter = Employee.FirstName.SubString(0, 1);
}
```

With that you get the first letter as a string and with this the character:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Employee.FirstName))
{
    char firstLetter = Employee.FirstName[0];
}
```

Comment: The first one returns a string, the second a char. Worth mentioning.

Comment: And you have a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`or an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the FirstName is empty

Comment: @JiBéDoublevé Of course you will have those exceptions. It was just a sample how to answer the question not to solve all problems may occur :-) I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
char firstCharOfFirstName = someEmployee.FirstName[0];
```

If the FirstName field can have leading whitespace you can do:

```
char firstCharOfFirstName = someEmployee.FirstName.Trim()[0];
```

(As the other answers mention it's good to check for empty string and `null` string)

Comment: I don't know who did the -1... +1 for perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 1):

If the first name might be empty, you would have to check that when getting the first letter:

```
FirstName.Substring(0, Math.Min(FirstName.Length, 1))
```

This will give you an empty string if the `FirstName` string is empty, otherwise the first character as a string, so that you can concatenate it with the last name.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind, SubString() or  FirstName[0] will throw a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException` if

```
FirstName == string.Empty
```

So, this code will at least avoid exception:

```
if(str2 != null)
{
    char result = (str2.Length > 0)
        ? str2[0]
        : (char)0;
}
```

Don't forget this code will return a false result if the string is empty!

Comment: +1 for mentioning `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` which other answers have neglected.

Comment: It doesn't handle the case where FirstName == null though.